# jQuery plugin to detect Konami cheat code sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, plugin

How can [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/dxPdw/) be written a bit shorter?

```
jQuery.konami = function(fn, code) {
    // ↑ ↑ ↓ ↓ ← → ← → B A
    code = code || [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65];

    var kkeys = '',
        i = 0;

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
        if (char === code[i++]) {
            kkeys += char;

            if (kkeys === code) {
                fn();
                kkeys = '';
                i = 0;
            }
        } else if (e.which === code[kkeys++]) {
            if (kkeys === code.length) {
                fn();
                kkeys = '';
                i = 0;
            }
        } else {
            kkeys = '';
            i = 0;
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is almost like code golf; this could probably be shortened.  You just need to keep track of `i` and when it's past the end of the array, you know all the keys were hit in the correct order.

```
jQuery.konami = function() {
    function KonamiCode(kFn, kCode) {
        var i = 0;

        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            var char = typeof kCode === 'string' ? String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase() : e.which;
            i = char === kCode[i] ? i + 1 : 0;
            if (i === kCode.length) {
                kFn();
                i = 0;
            }
        });
    }
    return function(fn, code) {
        // ↑ ↑ ↓ ↓ ← → ← → B A
        kCode = code || [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65];
        new KonamiCode(fn, kCode);
    };
}();
```

Comment: nice approach, but works not as expected...

Comment: @yckart what's wrong with it?

Comment: yeah it just simply isn't working, :p http://jsfiddle.net/dxPdw/5/ I haven't investigated as to why though

Comment: @NickLarsen it breaks on multiple instantiations and even fails with strings (words)... http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/dxPdw/6/

Comment: Silly logic error, `i = char === code[i] ? 0 : i + 1;` needed to be `i = char === code[i] ? i + 1 : 0;`.

Comment: @NickLarsen your updated answer works with strings but breaks now with  keycodes :P

Comment: This part is messing it up: `String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();` for the default version

Comment: @KevinB any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @yckart Yes, you would have to use an if statement like in your original. If the array is made up of strings, check the String.fromCharCode, else, compare against the e.which.

Comment: @KevinB yeah, had the same idea. Try around a bit...

Comment: Okay, git it... http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/dxPdw/10/

Comment: @yckart Yes, that's better than mine

Comment: hmm, can you explan a bit further what you mean with *resilient to multiple invocations*?

Comment: The original version is using the same `i` for every code, so if you invoke it twice with different codes they fail because they are competing for the same counter.  This change just makes it so every call gets it's own counter.

Comment: Okay, this is obvious... But the current approach without your "plugin wrapper" works even with multiple instantiations. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/dxPdw/

Comment: So where are the differences, or rather the dis/advantages?

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense actually, it's the keypress event handler that's holding the reference to a new local version if `i` each time.  That jsfiddle is just as good.

Comment: Okay, thanks alot for your help and time:-*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly shortened version:

```
jQuery.konami = function(fn, code) {
    // ↑ ↑ ↓ ↓ ← → ← → B A
    code = code || [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65];

    var i = 0;

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var char = $.type(code[i]) === "string" ? String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase() : e.which;
        if (char === code[i]) {
            i++;
            if (i == code.length) {
                fn();
                i = 0;
            }
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
    });
};
```

the kkeys var wasn't needed, and you could move the if else into the retrieval of `char`, allowing you to reuse what was inside the if originally.

http://jsfiddle.net/dxPdw/12/

Comment: Nice! However, got it already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647824/optimize-jquery-plugin-according-to-dry-principle/13647984#comment18725838_13647984 ;-)